# how do i change my website facebook login button to another text immediately user login?

Tags: plugins, login, facebook, session

i added a facebook login button to my website, this facebook button work well but even if a user is logged in, the facebook login still shows i need detail help or tutorial link that can help me change the text after login.

Comment: You need to ask the developers of the button. Has little to do with WordPress itself.

Comment: okay, thanks for your response i will contact them right now

Answer (score 1):

You can use WordPress function `is_user_logged_in()` to check if user if logged-in or not

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // print your facebook login button with login title text.
} else {
    // print your facebook login button with custom text.
}
```

Comment: wordpress doesn't seem to execute php code directly, is there any php plugin that you can suggest to execute the code you shared above?

Comment: WordPress already in PHP language. you dont need any kind of php plugin. 
try to wrap the above code in <?php  //here ?> PHP tags

Comment: i tried the code with the php tag as suggested, the page output the same source code

Comment: [ link ] (https://snag.gy/GStUMX.jpg)

Comment: You doing it in wrong way. 
give detail of your code file in question and description so that I can suggest you.

Comment: `[insert_php]                                                                                                                                   
if (!is_user_logged_in()){  
echo 'login' ;  
}  
else{  
echo 'logged' ;  
}  
[/insert_php]`

Comment: i used the above code with the help of a plugin (INSERT PHP) and it works fine the issue am now having is how to output html  `<a></a>`  instead of that echo statement

Comment: there is a "logged in user shortcode"  plugin that will do the same already without the need to mess with code. if the facebook button has a shortcode you could then do `[loggedin][facebook-login-button][/loggedin]` - depending what the button shortcode is.